# Cron job with multiple python commands doesnot append logs

Tags: python, cron

I am running following cron job in my system:

```
* * * * * python3 cront_test.py --week_day_num 7 && python3 hello.py >> /tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
```

But the log file shows logs for hello.py only. How can I add logs of both the python files to the same file

Also if cront_test.py is in sleeping mode won't logs be generated????

Comment: The shell cannot determine whether to run the second script until the first one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe `stdout/stderr` for both Shell commands, which are your Python scripts to the log file. As `&&` indicates to run `cront_test.py` first and if it ran successfully `hello.py` is started.

```
python3 cront_test.py --week_day_num >> /tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log 7 && python3 hello.py >> /tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
```